# Apps in Settings crashes in Android Q (Beta 3) emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-10.0

I'm having trouble when trying to open "Apps & Notifications" in Settings. When I try to do it, Settings crashes and the Launcher's Homescreen is shown.

```
Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}:
  java.lang.NullPointerException:
   Attempt to invoke virtual method
    'void com.android.settings.applications
     .SpecialAppAccessPreferenceController
     .setSession(com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.Lifecycle)'
on a null object reference`
```

This also happens when an App tries to open a Permissions Dialog (grant Overlay permission) or when I try to open the "App info" Activity for any app.

This is on a Windows 7 machine.

---

Here's a related entry in Google's issue tracker we can star: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132401131

---

Fixed in Beta 4

Comment: Same here on **Linux** (grant permission dialog & settings -> apps & noti.) and saw it on a colleague's **MacBook too** (settings -> apps & noti.)

Comment: Most likely you are tripping over bugs in the Settings app. Create a project that reproduces the error, then file a bug report.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't even need a project for this bug to occur. Just start the emulator and open Settings -> Apps &... makes it crash. :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought these were from your app trying to start Settings for those screens. Still, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently browsing the Issue Tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727%2B

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, it has aready been reported last week https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132401131 thanks for the hint.

Comment: There are 2 different API 29 Downloads available when creating a new emulated device in Android Studio: The first one with API Level "Q" with API 29 and the other one called: API Level "29" ("9+") both show API 29 with Google APIs and the latter one does NOT crash on my setup. I can navigate to system settings App and also starting Activity from a Service does work (like it should, regarding to documentation for Q?) I hope that is the "real/correct" one and not that buggy piece of "Q" emu.

Comment: @Ben This issue got resolved with the Beta 4 which got released a few days before or on Jun 6. If you delete all you Q-Downloads and then install "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 5)", then it should work.

Comment: @Daniel F Thanks - good to know, I still have that other Q installed and thought updating the SDK and AS would fix it one day, but obviously it did not. I'll do so!